# python: How to count the frequency of given elements in a list

Tags: python, counter

I understand the counter function counts the frequency of every element in a list. But I would like it to include the frequency from given elements even the element doesn't appear in the list.

for example:

A list of expected elements are given as:

```
expected_element = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

for the datasets a,b:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,6,6,6,3,3,4,5,5]
b = [2,2,7,1,7,5,3,5,5]
```

and what I want is to count frequency of expected_element in a and b:

for a:

```
keys() =   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
values() = [4,0,2,1,2,3,0]
```

for b:

```
keys() =   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
values() = [1,2,1,0,3,0,2]
```

Comment: did you try anything? This is rather trivial.

Comment: did you google it?

Comment: Did you try list comprehension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question in reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with the unique keys in `set(a)`, paired with null values, then update it with `Counter(b)`:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,1,1,1,6,6,6,3,3,4,5,5]
b = [2,2,7,1,7,5,3,5,5]

frequencies = {key: 0 for key in set(a)}
frequencies.update(Counter(b))
print(frequencies)
```

#### output:

```
{1: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 3, 6: 0, 2: 2, 7: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict

```
expected_element = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = [1,1,1,1,6,6,6,3,3,4,5,5]
b = [2,2,7,1,7,5,3,5,5]

a_occurance = dict()
b_occurance = dict()
for i in expected_element:
    a_occurance[i]=0
    b_occurance[i]=0
for i in a:
    a_occurance[i]+=1
for i in b:
    b_occurance[i]+=1

print a_occurance.keys()
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print a_occurance.values()
# [4, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0]
print b_occurance.keys()
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print b_occurance.values()
# [1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2]
```